# Python TypeError: must be str, not int for a String

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, typeerror, string-concatenation

I'm working on a Python(3.6) project in which I need to append an integer value to a multiline string.

Here's My code:

```
    for var in list(range(1, no_of_svc + 1)):
        svar = str(var)
        print(type(svar))
        port = type(data['configuration']['svc' + svar]['port']['port'])
        print(port)
        port = str(data['configuration']['svc' + svar]['port']['port'])
        deployments = deployment + '''\n
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ''' + data['deployment_name'] + '''-''' + data['configuration']['svc' + str(var)]['name'] + '''
  labels:
    #Project ID
    app: ''' + data['configuration']['svc' + str(var)]['name'] + '''
spec:
  #Run two instances of our application
  replicas: ''' + data['configuration']['svc' + str(var)]['replicas'] + '''
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ''' + data['configuration']['svc' + str(var)]['name'] + '''
    spec:
      #Container details
      containers:
        - name: ''' + data['configuration']['svc' + str(var)]['versions']['v1']['name'] + '''
          image: ''' + data['configuration']['svc' + str(var)]['versions']['v1']['image'] + '''
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          #Ports to expose
          ports:
          - containerPort: ''' + port + '''        
'''
```

As you can see in the code above I have converted `port` to string and even the output of `print(type(svar))` and `print(port)` is `<class 'str'>` but still it's not working.

Here's the error message:

```
   - containerPort: ''' + port + '''
 TypeError: must be str, not int
```

> **I have turned it by using the `format` method and it's working:**

```
    no_of_svc = int(data['configuration']['no_of_svc'])
    deployment = ''
    deployments = ''''''
    for var in list(range(1, no_of_svc + 1)):
        deployments = deployment + '''\n
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {}
  labels:
    #Project ID
    app: {}
spec:
  #Run two instances of our application
  replicas: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {}
    spec:
      #Container details
      containers:
        - name: {}
          image: {}
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          #Ports to expose
          ports:
          - containerPort: {}        
'''.format(data['deployment_name'] + '-' + data['configuration']['svc' + str(var)]['name'],
           data['configuration']['svc' + str(var)]['name'],
           data['configuration']['svc' + str(var)]['replicas'],
           data['configuration']['svc' + str(var)]['name'],
           data['configuration']['svc' + str(var)]['versions']['v1']['name'],
           data['configuration']['svc' + str(var)]['versions']['v1']['image'],
           data['configuration']['svc' + str(var)]['port']['port'])
    print(deployments)
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: Which line are you getting the error?

Comment: updated, take a look again, please!

Comment: why don't put it in str(port) ?

Comment: That is one of the good reasons to use `format()`. `deployments = """blah {foo} blah {bar}""".format(foo=config['foo'], bar=bar)`

Comment: you could either use `.format` or use `str(port)`

Comment: `str(port)` also return the same error!

Comment: How do you know it is `port`?  It could be `deployment`, that's part of the same statement or any of the other values in that string.  The error message is there because `port` is at the end of the string, check all the others.

Comment: Have you balanced all triple quotes correctly ?

Comment: Hi @jazz, I have double checked it!

Comment: Then as suggested by others, please provide full objects view used(after removing sensitive data). As concatenation what you gave here if rendered in Python 3.6.5 gave no such error even if port is initialized as an int value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `format` to put value of `port` in your string.

See this:-

```
>>> port = 'my string1'
>>> str1 = ''' this is the second string and here is {} '''.format(port)
>>> str1
' this is the second string and here is my string1 '
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message / traceback points you to the place where the error was detected, not necessarly the point where it really happens. We can't reproduce the error since you didn't post a proper MCVE (we don't know what's in your `data`) but chances are the real problem is actually in one of the numerous other values concatenated from `data` upper in the code (remember that for python the whole `deployment = deployment + '''(...)'''` is a single statement.

But anyway: **you're doing it wrong right from the start**. Instead of concatenation, you want to [use string formatting operations](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#format-examples), which are much more readable AND will take care of the necessary conversions.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment?